# How to argue some of following maps form $\mathbb Z\to Q$ are not possible?

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory, examples-counterexamples

{$f:Z\to Q|$f is bijective and monotonically increasing}

Actually I only now that there is function bijective form $N\to N\times N$ I can make it from $Z\to N\times N$.

But after that I could not know.

I wanted to know that how to argue that map are not possible .

Any Help will be appreciated

Comment: Asking 4 questions in one post is not something we like to see on this site. Also, asking questions and no effort put into them is looked down upon.

Comment: @5xum Sorry for that . If you provide me some hint so that I could proceed. I had edited question

Comment: [Closely related](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2146045/28900).

Comment: Hint : Between any two rationals there is always another rational. Is this true for integers? Now, try to prove that any monotonically increasing map from $\mathbb Z$ to $\mathbb Q$ cannot be surjective.

Comment: Ah you deleted the problems?  where did you get the problems? I want to try them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint**:

Use proof by contradiction

**Hint 2**:

Think about what value $z\in\mathbb Z$ maps to the number $\frac{f(0)+f(1)}{2}$. Remember, $a<\frac{a+b}{2}<b$ if $a<b$.

Comment: Nice hint .I got question answer now...